# An example for AWSConfigs.GetConfig in C#

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services

I want to read the AWS specific config sections, and I could see there is an API method for the same in .NET 3 SDK.

```cs
AWSConfigs.GetConfig()
```

From
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Amazon/MAWSConfigsGetConfigString.html

I couldnt find any code samples. I wanted to read arbitrary values in the  section of the config file, like the

```xml
<IdentityPoolId></IdentityPoolId>
```

as shown below.

```xml
<aws profileName="dev" profilesLocation="C:\temp\awscredentials\credentials-file">
    <IdentityPoolId>eu-west-1:62484b27-39ce-4db8-8bcb</IdentityPoolId>
</aws>
```

Any help much appreciated.